# How do I approach the coupon collector's problem if multiple items belong to different "families"?

Tags: probability, statistics, coupon-collector

Say we roll a fair six-sided dice, and our goal is to roll every number at least once. The expected number of rolls is fairly simple: we find $E(x)=\int_0^\infty(1-(1-e^{-\frac{t}{6}})^6)dt=6(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6})=14.7$.

However, say instead that our goal is to not roll every number at least once, but to roll three different numbers, each one from a different family - we want $a,b,$ and $c$ such that $a$ is an even number, $b$ is a prime number, and $c$ is a square number, with the stipulation that $a\neq b\neq c$. So, we want an element from $A=\{2,4,6\}$, one from $B=\{2,3,5\}$, and one from $C=\{1,4\}$, and we don't want any duplicates. What is the expected number of rolls to complete *this* task?

Without the no-duplicates rule, this is still simple. It would be $E(X)=\int_0^\infty(1-(1-e^{-\frac{t}{2}})^2(1-e^{-\frac{t}{3}}))dt=4.35$. However, *with* the rule, it becomes more difficult. I've considered going on a case-by-case basis - that is, if our first roll is 1, then we look at the probability of getting different members of $A$ and $B$, if we roll a 2, we look at the probability of getting either different members from $B/\{2\}$ and $C$ or $A/\{2\}$ and $C$, and so on - but I wanted to know if there's a faster way to do this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If the first roll is $4$, say, how do we know whether it is from family $A$ or family $C$?

Comment: Truthfully, I envisioned it as sort of a "greedy" sorting system - if we roll a 4 first, and then a 1, we would say that 4 was in $A$, but if we rolled a 2 or a 6 next, we'd say 4 was in $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result without the no-duplicates rule is wrong, so let’s derive the correct result for that case, first.

Let $X$ be the number or rolls required, and let $A_x$, $B_x$, $C_x$ denote the events that no number in the corresponding family has been rolled yet. Then, by [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle),

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathsf E[X]&=&\sum_{x=0}^\infty\mathsf P(X>x)\\
&=&\sum_{x=0}^\infty\mathsf P(A_x\cup B_x\cup C_x)\\
&=&\sum_{x=0}^\infty(\mathsf P(A_x)+\mathsf P(B_x)+\mathsf P(C_x)-\mathsf P(A_x\cap B_x)-\mathsf P(A_x\cap C_x)-\mathsf P(B_x\cap C_x)\\&&\quad{}+\mathsf P(A_x\cap B_x\cap C_x))\\[5pt]
&=&6\left(\frac13+\frac13+\frac12-\frac15-\frac14-\frac15+\frac16\right)\\[5pt]
&=&4.1\;.
\end{eqnarray}

The result is confirmed by simulations using [this Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/b458c6bc745fd9351dfe1eea89860aa2).

If I understand your no-duplicates rule correctly, the process terminates once we’ve rolled all three rolls in one of the thirteen triples in

$$T=\{123,124,125,126,134,136,145,156,234,245,246,346,456\}\;,$$

where to reduce notational clutter I denoted e.g. the triple $\{1,2,3\}$ by $123$. Let $Y$ denote the number of rolls required, and for a triple $t\in T$, let $E_t$ denote the event that not all rolls in $t$ have been rolled yet. Then, again by inclusion–exclusion,

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathsf E[Y]&=&\sum_{y=0}^\infty\mathsf P\left(\bigcup_{t\in T}E_t\right)\\
&=&\sum_{y=0}^\infty\sum_{\emptyset\neq S\subseteq T}(-1)^{|S|+1}\mathsf P\left(\bigcap_{t\in S}E_t\right)\\
&=&\sum_{\emptyset\neq S\subseteq T}(-1)^{|S|+1}\sum_{y=0}^\infty\mathsf P\left(\bigcap_{t\in S}E_t\right)\\
&=&6\sum_{\emptyset\neq S\subseteq T}(-1)^{|S|+1}H_{\left|\bigcup_{t\in S}t\right|}\;,
\end{eqnarray}

where $H_n$ is the $n$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). [This Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/9cd56577b07d870139c67e009c86dd5e) adds up the $2^{13}-1$ terms in this sum; the result is

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathsf E[Y]&=&6(13H_3-25H_4+17H_5-4H_6)\\
&=&6\left(1+\frac12+\frac13-\frac{12}4+\frac{13}5-\frac46\right)\\
&=&4.6\;.
\end{eqnarray}

The result is confirmed by simulations also performed by that code.

Thus, the no-duplicates rule increases the expected number of required rolls by half a roll.

Comment: P.S.: I realized afterwards that I might have misunderstood how the version without the no-duplicates rule is supposed to work. Above, I assumed that e.g. getting a $2$ and a $4$ would be enough, since the $2$ covers both $A$ and $B$. Perhaps you meant that we need two $2$s to cover both $A$ and $B$. [This Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/be220f8de517c61fcb445c47c13c2164) simulates that version and yields an expected number of rolls around $4.44$, so your result of $4.35$ wouldn't be the right result for that version, either. I can't think of any other interpretation of the setup.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, after the clarifications you have given subsequent to my posting an answer based on my understanding of the question, I doubt whether a cut and dried formula can be given the way you have given for other cases. Some sort of dynamic programming seems to be indicated.

Comment: Sorry, I think I should have clarified - the goal is not to get one of each number. The goal is simply to get one representative element from each set. If we rolled 1 for C, 4 for A, and then 2 for B, we would be done, since we have three distinct elements from A, B, and C

Comment: But you are asking for the expected # of rolls to complete the task. If you don't get one each from $A,B,C$ in $3$ rolls, the fourth one is bound to be  from a duplicate family ?

Comment: Not necessarily. Say we roll 2, 3, 6, 1. We failed to get one from $A$ in the first three rolls, but got it by the fourth roll. In fact, since there is at least one unique member in each set, it is always possible to fulfill the task.